# WIX Pre-installation check : If a folder already exists

Tags: xml, wix, windows-installer

I am new to WIX TOOLSET, and was playing around with it. Was trying to program and installer, but stuck at a point, wherein I need to pre-search before installation if certain file/folder exists, if yes then proceed else halt the process. But I am not able to find a clear solution for it. here is my code.

```
<Property Id="CHECKPREINSTALLATION">
  <DirectorySearch Path="[ProgramsFilesFolder]"
                   Depth="0"
                   AssignToProperty="no"
                   Id="ProgramFilesFolderSearch">
    <DirectorySearch Path="Notepad"
                     Depth="0"
                     AssignToProperty="no"
                     Id="ComprionFolderSearch">
      <DirectorySearch Path="plugin"
                       Depth="0"
                       AssignToProperty="no"
                       Id="DeviceTestCenterFolderSearch">

      </DirectorySearch>
    </DirectorySearch>
  </DirectorySearch>
</Property>




<Condition Message="Installation requires PLUGIN. Please make sure it is installed."> NOT CHECKPREINSTALLATION</Condition>
```

Would be great if some one could give some suggestions on a correct way of doing it.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem.  I want to check for the existence of a known folder and if it exists, I want to alert the user and abort the install.  My folder is not under Program Files, it is a root level folder.  Why might I want to do this?  Because a user created a folder name that collides with my application name and I don't want to overwrite their folder or fail silently.  This seems like a very, very routine operation and I am sure it is possible in WiX, I can't figure out how.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, Path attribute of DirectorySearch is quite picky.
You should use something like [System Folders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Msi/property-reference#system_folder_properties) to begin with, and then just add path instead of nested DirectorySearch tag. So, in your situation:

```
Path="[ProgramFilesFolder]Notepad\plugin"
```

Next, you can predefine Property value. If folder is found, value will be changed to its address, so you can base your condition on that. 
Full code:

```
<Property Id="CHECKPREINSTALLATION" Value="NOTEXIST" >
      <DirectorySearch Id="ProgramFilesFolderSearch" Depth="0" Path="[ProgramFilesFolder]Notepad\plugin" >
      </DirectorySearch>
    </Property>

    <Condition Message="Installation requires PLUGIN. Please make sure it is installed.">
      <![CDATA[CHECKPREINSTALLATION<>"NOTEXIST"]]>
    </Condition>
```

If you want choose path between two folders (like me) just use double DirectorySearch. Address of the latest existing folder will be used in property, like so:

```
<Property Id="CHECKPREINSTALLATION"  >
      <DirectorySearch Id="ProgramFilesFolderSearch" Depth="0" Path="[ProgramFilesFolder]Notepad\folderA" >
      </DirectorySearch>
 <DirectorySearch Id="ProgramFilesFolderSearch2" Depth="0" Path="[ProgramFilesFolder]Notepad\folderB" >
      </DirectorySearch>
    </Property>
```

I know that this is old question and will not help author, but I was searching for solid answer and could not find one.

Answer (score -1):

It looks as if you are doing a file search to determine if something is already installed. If that something was installed by an MSI product there are other ways to search for it (component guid, for example, and sometimes a registry search). Or maybe the file is part of a standard redistributable that you can just run and it will do the right thing anyway.

The other thing is that a search in the Program Files folder is tricky because there are two of them on x64 machines, one for 32-bit and another for 64-bit, so there's room for confusion. Also, when somebody installs a product they can choose the install folder, so there is no guarantee that Program Files is the right place to look.

Edit add:
I'm not getting something here. Your setup installs files to that program files folder. But your question is how your install can detect a previous version, or folder that you previously put there? That implies that you are doing an upgrade of some kind, and at that point I get lost because upgrades just work - if the file is already there it gets updated or not based on version rules. On the other hand if you are installing a completely different product that is not an upgrade, you just need to search for the component guid of that file and it will tell you whether it's there or not. Either way, I don't know how to answer the question because if my analysis is correct, you don't need the search.  Either way, file searches do work, and they set a property if a file is found, and if you do the install and create a log you'll see what's going on and if the property is being set. If it's a file you want, do a file search not a directory search, if it's the presence of the file that matters.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but that dosent solve my problem. As you could see in my code, i have referred to [ProgramsFilesFolder], which means 32-bit, according to the convention. Any yes my files are in this folder only Program Files (x86). Which means i called it correctly.

Comment: You may have missed the point - the ProgramFilesFolder comment was only to remind you that you that: 1) You might not be looking in the right place x64/x86. 2. The target folder can usually be changed by a browse dialog during the install, and if that's the case then the files won't be there.  I don't understand "your files are in the folder". That search is a search that doesn't have anything to do with your files, it's just a search in your install for files in some location, and nothing to do with where your files might be installed.

Comment: Thanks again for patience. I agree with you, but the fact remains 1) that my installer installs the file at a specific location and dosent ask user for custom path 2) and secondly this is a preinstallation check, so i just need to know before i install my msi file, if a specific folder already exists( that is why i do the search, and this search is a directory search to just find that folder(as it is always installed in C:/ and an absolute path preselected). I hope you get what i mean now.